# Stuck in black screen in ubuntu 23.04 while installing nvidia drivers in for 410M graphics which has only external display via hdmi

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display, hdmi

I have tried most of the methods and workarounds in installing the proprietary nvidia drivers in old Sony Vaio laptop([VPCEH25EN](https://www.sony.co.in/electronics/support/laptop-pc-vpc-series/vpceh25en/specifications)) which has the same stock specs. Every time the nvidia 390 drivers which to my knowledge is for 410M graphics card, installs without any errors  installation and the on typing commands:

1. `lsmod | grep 'nvidia'` (Getting some nvidia file names as output)
2. `sudo lshw -c  video | grep 'configuration'` (shows configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0)
   from ttyl screen, but then also I can't able to fix.